# Python C API. Pass pointer to C++ function to existing Python file

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++11, python-c-api

I Have a C++ code that calls a function named "function" of a python script named "filename".

```
PyObject module= PyImport_ImportModule("filename");
PyObject *python_fn = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, (char *)"function");
PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(0);
PyObject_CallObject(python_fn , args);
```

The function is called correctly. Now I want to be able to pass to the python module a pointer to a C function. 
I tried with the `PyImport_AppendInittab` as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_AppendInittab) but I had no luck.

Any suggestion?

Thanks 
H.

Comment: How is this c++11?

Comment: I am open to solutions in C++11.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're actually trying to do here - the code you have has is pretty unrelated to passing a C function pointer. Do you want to pass a C function pointer to a function that expects a Python callable? (`Inittab` is to do with setting up built-in modules without needing an .so file so I don't think that applies here)

Comment: The code is what I have right now. It is not code that is not functioning.I would like to add the functionality that I can pass the C function pointer and call that function from python.
Sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass a C/C++ function pointer to a Python function you need to convert it into a Python object (since all arguments to Python functions must be Python objects). You can create a DIY version with an outline something like this:

```
typedef struct {
   PyObject_HEAD
   int (*ptr)(int, int); // assuming this matches the signature of the function pointer
} MyFuncPtr;

PyObject* Call_MyFuncPtr(MyFuncPtr* self, PyObject* args, PyObject* kwargs) {
  // implementation goes here...
  //  you probably want to convert the Python arguments to C with PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords
  //  call the function
  //  then convert the C return value back to a PyObject* and return that
}
```

The associated `PyTypeObject` is defined pretty as in [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html) - the only change you need to make is to set `tp_call` to `Call_MyFuncPtr` so that the type is callable in Python (you may need a cast here - the signatures don't quite match because of the type of the first argument). You don't need to add it to a module object (since it'll only be accessible from C anyway) but you do need to call `PyType_Ready` on it.

You'd then allocate it using

```
MyFuncPtr* mfp = PyObject_New(MyFuncPtr,&MyFuncPtr_Type)
mfp->ptr = // some matching C/C++ function
```

and pass it is an argument to Python using a standard C API function call.

---

It's possible that there you want to avoid doing this yourself and use an existing library. For C++, Boost Python defines [a nice wrapper](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/boost_python_make_function_hpp.html) that automatically does this, as does [PyBind11](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/functional.html). You might also be able to use the Ctypes or CFFI libraries, but it isn't immediately obvious to me how you interface with them from C or C++.